# No SSL padlock in browsers

Tags: ssl

My SSL padlock for the checkout page is not showing:
https://www.startupacademy.ro/finalizare-plata-integrala/

I used https://www.whynopadlock.com/ to debug the problem and it returned this:

> Insecure  call.  Found on line # 158 in file:
>   www.startupacademy.ro/finalizare-plata-integrala/index.html

I can't find the problem? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Your form posts to an insecure URL:

```
<form name="formular" action="http://www.startupacademy.ro/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.startupacademy.ro%2F" method="post">
```

I suspect should be:

```
<form name="formular" action="https://www.startupacademy.ro/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.startupacademy.ro%2F" method="post">
```

**Edit**: you are also doing a bunch of AJAX requests to non-secure URL's.

Comment: I changed that line and all the AJAX requests and still no padlock... Any other suggestions? I appreciate the help.

Comment: Can you post a screen shot showing what you mean?  I viewed your site in Firefox and I can see a padlock.

Comment: Maybe you need to refresh the browser cache.  I just had a look in Chrome and it's fine.